# CSS Transitions not working in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to have a portion of my code fade into view if a button is clicked. I am basing it on this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/srEwWJvZf65LzmU3cbOX?p=preview

Here's the HTML of the demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.11/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.11" data-require="angular.js@1.3.11"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-animate@1.3.11" data-semver="1.3.11" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.11/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-init="show=false" ng-app="ngAnimate">
    <button ng-click="show=!show">Toggle content</button>
    <div ng-if="show" class="content">Look at my lovely content</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here are the demo styles:

```
.content {
  padding: 10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

.content.ng-enter,
.content.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  max-height:0;
}

.content.ng-leave,
.content.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  max-height:1em;
}
```

The demo used height rather than opacity, but it can be quickly edited to do opacity fade ins.

My code does not work like this. I am attempting to do the same thing to .container, which is towards the top. Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Multiplication Table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-animate@1.3.11" data-semver="1.3.11" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.11/angular-animate.js"></script>    
</head>
<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
    <header>
        <h2><span style="font-weight: 800;">Waiter</span><span style="font-weight: 40;">Dock</span><img src="logo.png" alt="logo" width="32px" id="logo" /></h2>
    </header>
    <div class="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div class="container" ng-if="started">
            <div class="half dark">
                <div class="half-top">
                    <h3>Enter Meal Details</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="half-bottom">
                   <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
                        <div>
                            <p class="error" ng-if="myForm.base.$error.pattern">Base must be a number</p>
                            <input type="text" name="base" ng-model="$parent.data.base" ng-pattern="/[0-9]/" 
                                placeholder="Base price" required />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p class="error" ng-if="myForm.tax.$error.pattern">Tax rate must be a number</p>
                            <input type="text" name="tax" ng-model="$parent.data.taxRate" ng-pattern="/[0-9]/" 
                                placeholder="Tax rate" required  />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p class="error" ng-if="myForm.tip.$error.pattern">Tip percentage must be a number</p>
                            <input type="text" name="tip" ng-model="$parent.data.tip" ng-pattern="/[0-9]/" 
                                placeholder="Tip" required />
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit">Submit</button><button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="half-right">
                <div class="dark half-right-inner "> 
                    <div class="half-top">
                        <h3>My Earnings Information</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="half-bottom-right">
                        <p>Tip Total: {{ tiptotal | currency }}</p>
                        <p>Meal count: {{ mealcount }}</p>
                        <p ng-if="averageTip">Average Tip: {{ averageTip | currency }}</p>
                        <p class="details" ng-if="total" ng-click="toggleDetails()">Details</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="transaction dark half-right-inner half-right-inner-bottom" ng-if="details"> 
                    <div class="half-top">    
                        <h3>Last Transaction</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="half-bottom-right">
                        <p>Subtotal: {{ subtotal | currency }} </p>
                        <p>Tip: {{ displayTip | currency }}</p>
                        <p class="total"><b>{{ subtotal | currency }} + {{ displayTip | currency }} = {{ total | currency }}</b></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="welcome-container" ng-if="!started">
            <div id="welcome">
                <h2>Welcome to</h2>
                <h1>
                    WaiterDock
                </h1>
                <button ng-click="startApp()">Get Started</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the portion of my CSS that imitates the demo:

```
.container {
    display: flex; 
    align-items: top; 
    transition: all linear 0.5s; 
}

.container.ng-enter,
.container.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}

.container.ng-leave,
.container.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? This looks to exactly like the demo. But it isn't working..? It just toggles straight to the div without fading it in. Help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a specific technical answer, as there is not enough information to diagnose the exact cause, but it appears you are using mismatched version numbers of AngularJS and ngAnimate. I don't think this is supported.

Indeed when I try to run the example but change the version number to the 1.5.5 that you are using then the animation stops working and I get the following error in the console.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider <- $$asyncCallback <- $animate <- $compile

That's certainly not going to help. I would suggest checking for JavaScript errors in the console, and using the corresponding ngAnimate version for your version of Angular.

With a new version of ngAnimate the animation may still need some tweaking if anything has changed in the way ngAnimate works, but at least it should be working at all.

**Update**

As per your comment I thought I'd take another closer look at the example and, my first reaction is "What the..?". No. Don't use this example. Here are a few tips.

1. `ngAnimate` is not your app but a module that you import into your app. That would have been a major reason why the code wasn't working. I understand that the Angular team have had headaches with people monkey patching the core ng* modules. Using a core ng* module as your app is taking that to a whole new level.
2. You probably don't want to use `ng-if` in this situation, instead I suggest you use `ng-show` / `ng-hide`. The difference is that ng-if will literally take the elements out of the DOM while show and hide will, well, show and hide. It's easier to animate the latter than the former.
3. The CSS in the example seems overly complicated. You can usually just put the name of the animation as a class name for how you want it to end up. The CSS transition takes care of the rest.

Please see my improved example. Hopefully you'll find this a better guide.

```js
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module("exampleApp", ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller("exampleController", function($scope) {

  $scope.show = false;

  $scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
  }
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.content.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="exampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="exampleController">
    <button ng-click="toggle()">Toggle content</button>
    <div ng-show="show" class="content">Look at my lovely content</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I actually tried that (good thought) and it just does the same thing. No transition. Very weird.

Comment: @JSeabolt I have updated my answer with more details. There are a few things wrong with the original example and I have fixed them